# Error is not displaying in controller using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

I am developing a website in codeigniter. While I am trying to access controller function it gives white space screen rather than error specific. I have tried to put `error_reporting(e_all)` in my function name but no luck.

Below is my controller function

```
function update_something($post)
{
    error_reporting(e_all);
}
```

How to enable error in CI?

Comment: I would checkout the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) hopefully that will point you in the right direction

Comment: [Error reporting is on by default in CI3.](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) See index.php in your root directory for details. Sounds like `update_something()` isn't getting called? Maybe put a `dump_var($post);` and `exit();` at the top of it?

Comment: @nikunj i have read post as per your suggestion,its working for me now,thanks.